# Convert time in laravel from 2 inputs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6.2

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 6.
I have 2 inputs:

```
<input maxlength="5" type="text" name="hours_worked" class="form-control edited valid" value="" required="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">

<input type="text" name="minutes_worked" class="form-control edited valid" value="" required="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

I save to db with this code:

```
WorkingTime::create( $this->request->all()
```

I have a problem when someone types in the field, for example. "90" minutes. I have 90 minutes saved in the database - and I would like to save 1h and 30 minutes.

How can I achieve this with my code?

My schema:

```
Schema::create('working_times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('case_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('case_id')->references('id')->on('case_instances')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->smallInteger('hours_worked');
            $table->smallInteger('minutes_worked');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('appearance')->nullable();
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Easy way : `date('H:i', mktime(0,90));`

Comment: _I would like to save 1h and 30 minutes._ what does it mean? what type of field do you have in your database?

Comment: Can you share the schema for WorkingTIme and a dd of $request->all() please :)

Comment: I update my post - add schema

Comment: just like @STA said use `date('H:i', mktime($request->input('hours_worked'),$request->input('minutes_worked')));` the first param is for hours the second is for minutes.

Comment: @Bobby, he mentioned `90` minute

Comment: @operloa you can't insert string in `smallInteger`,  but you can convert minute to hour, minute when show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a crude solution, but instead of doing:

```
WorkingTime::create($this->request->all());
```

Do:

```
$data = $this->request->all();
$hours = (int) $data['hours_worked'];
$minutes = (int) $data['minutes_worked'];
$overMinutes = $minutes % 60;
$hours += (int) (($minutes - $overMinutes) / 60);
$minutes = $overMinutes;

$data['hours_worked'] = $hours;
$data['minutes_worked'] = $minutes;

WorkingTime::create($data);
```